# Kernel versions

Tags: kernel

I use Ukuu to manage kernels.

It currently tells me

```
Version 4.17.8 is installed.

Version 4.15.0.23.25 is running.
```

Whenever I install a new kernel, the 4.15 version always stays.

Is that o.k.?

Comment: Yes, it is normal.

Comment: Are you wanting to go to those other kernels you install?  If you are, you will have to reboot to them.  However, one thing you need to keep in mind is that when you install those kernels from ukuu they are meant to be for testing purposes only.

Comment: The point releases may be for testing, but not the major versions.